# Azure internal load balancer in backend pool of application gateway

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

It may not be a good idea, but it is possible to configure internal load balancer in backend pool of application gateway. It looks like a two-level load balancing, the first level at application proxy and the second level at internal load balancer.

Is there any concern for this design?

Comment: Any updates for the question? Does it solve your problem? I didn't see any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem with the design. While the internal load balancer just balances the traffic from the internal resources. So if you want to access the backend of the load balancer, the application gateway is a good choice.

Maybe you would say, only use the application gateway also can access the backend. The application gateway and the load balancer focus on different features, this design can use the features both of them and make themselves just focus on their own jobs only. I think it's a cool design.